# How to use 'between' in select statement

Tags: php, mysql

This is supposed to be an easy solution but i can't my ahead around it.
I have a table [image]

Here is a my query

```
 $salary=2000;  

select deductions from nhif_tbl where to_end <=$salary and start_from >= $salary;
```

The query returns null.
My question how do i modify the query in order to get correct deductions in this case '60'

Comment: Shouldn't it be `select deductions from nhif_tbl where to_end >=$salary and start_from <= $salary;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select deductions from nhif_tbl where to_end >=$salary and start_from <= $salary;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `to_end` should be 999 more than the `start_from`

```
$salary=2000;  
select deductions from nhif_tbl 
where to_end >=$salary and start_from <= $salary;
```

Comment: Two of them are only 499 apart.

Comment: What if salary is 1000?

Comment: Yes, the logic shouldn't be like this. This solution comes to my head very first and post it! Changing...

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
select deductions from nhif_tbl where to_end >=$salary and start_from <= $salary;
```

Answer (score 0):

that's obvious try to revers the condition!

```
....where to_end >=$salary and start_from <= $salary;
```

let's do some analyses for the conditions
when it's starts the condition to_ens<=2000
it's grabs the first and the second line, 
and when jumps next to the second condition start_from >= 2000... well you got my point!